# Change `cmake` location

Tags: software-installation, environment-variables, cmake

At the moment, I do not have `sudo` rights to a compute cluster. I am installing the `hdf5` module locally with my user account. This module needs `cmake` for `building`. However, the default `cmake` available in the cluster is 2.8.12.2. But, the build process says it needs `CMake 3.1.0 or higher`.

So I downloaded a higher version `cmake` and built it. How do I to change the default `cmake` location in the cluster to the newly installed location? I know it's the environment variable. But I do not know which one exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Install your cmake in `~/bin/`, and add `~/bin/` to the beginning of your `PATH`. You may have to `mkdir -m 0755 ~/bin/` first.